# How to return documents where value is found in an array? Mongoose.js

Tags: mongoose

I am simply trying to return all documents (sites) where req.user._id is found, within an array of subdocuments (managers).

The user can manage multiple sites, so I need a way to list all of these associated sites.

```
Site.find({}).elemMatch('managers', {_id: req.user._id}).exec((err, sites) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
  }
    return res.json(sites)
});
```

I've tried [Mongoose elemMatch](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch) with no luck.
I can't locate this in the docs anywhere, but it seems like a simple query to run.

(edited) Here is a sample schema and doc:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const SiteSchema = new Schema({
  city: {
           type: String
  },
  siteRef: {
           type: String
  },
  managers: [{
           type: Schema.ObjectId,
             ref: 'User'
  }],
});


export default mongoose.model('Site', SiteSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElemMatch would not be the best querying method for this because you are attempting to reach within a subdocment for your query.

I believe you are looking for [mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

Try something like this:

```
Site.find().populate('managers', null, req.user._id).exec((err, managers) => {
  if (err) {
      return (err)
  }
    return res.json(sites)
});
```

For a better understanding of what's happening look at the example they provide:

```
Kitten.find().populate({
    path: 'owner'
  , select: 'name'
  , match: { color: 'black' }
  , options: { sort: { name: -1 }}
}).exec(function (err, kittens) {
  console.log(kittens[0].owner.name) // Zoopa
})

// alternatively
Kitten.find().populate('owner', 'name', null, {sort: { name: -1 }}).exec(function (err, kittens) {
  console.log(kittens[0].owner.name) // Zoopa
})
```

"path" in your case would be "managers" and you are returning all sites where "req.user._id" matches any of the fields in the model.